# Have I messed up this converence sequence question?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

[image]

So in solving this question have I messed up the first line.

In further work should the inequality sign on the end of the first line be > instead of <

Thanks

Comment: Can you not use the algebraic limit theorems or whatever your book calls them?  If not then remember that $5/n - 2/n^2 < 5/n$ then use AP and transitivity.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows Isn't it better to check OP's work rather than offer an alternative solution?

Comment: I have two comments.  First, instead of writing $1$ divided by $n$ in the way you did before the "so then" part, you should keep it as $\frac{1}{n}$.  Same goes for $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$.  Also, you've said for all $n \geq N$, $\frac{1}{n^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{n} < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, and then you said that this implies $\frac{5}{n} - \frac{2}{n^{2}} < \frac{5 \epsilon}{3} - \frac{2 \epsilon}{3}$.  Are you sure about this?  I need to think about it more, so I'm not saying you're wrong, but are you sure it's right?  **EDIT** I've thought about it, and I don't think it's right.

Comment: You can fix the issue I mentioned in my last comment by using the hint provided in the posted answer.

Comment: @user46944 Sorry I didn't make it clear.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows thanks for the reply, I have solved it correctly in terms of limits but was trying to apply archimedean's property - in case of a specific method is required. :)

Comment: Thank you @user46944 excellent advice, was only following how this course book wrote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$ \frac{5}{n} - \frac{2}{n^2} \leq \frac{5}{n}. $$

Comment: Your answer does nothing to communicate to OP whether their work is right or wrong.

Comment: Working with $\frac{2}{n^2}$ just makes the process tedious.

Comment: Thank you so the inequality sign should then be ≤ ?

Comment: Which "$\leq$" are you referring to? 

For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that $\frac{5}{n} - \frac{2}{n^2} \leq \frac{5}{n}< \epsilon$ for every $n>N$.

Comment: Great thank you that is what I was asking, but should I have a modulus sign for the LHS of the inequality?

Comment: Okay, glad to be of help. And yes, and you have perfectly used the fact that $|x| < x$.